# Question about proof regarding sigma field generated by random vector

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables

I have just read the following theorem, and I don't understand its proof:

Let $X=(X_1,...,X_k)$ be a random vector. Then the $\sigma$-field $\sigma(X)$ consists exactly of the sets $[X\in H]$ where $H$ is a borel set of $R^k$.

Edit: Our definition of $\sigma(X)$ is $\sigma(X)$ is the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras with respect to which $X$ is measurable.
The proof is as follows:

The class $G$ of sets of the form $[X\in H]$ for $H\in B(R^k)$ is a $\sigma$-field. Since $X$ is measurable $\sigma(X)$, it follows that $G$ is a subset of $\sigma(X)$. Because $X$ is measurable $G$, it follows that $\sigma(X)$ is a subset of $G.

My question is, why is $G$ a subset of $\sigma(X)$, and why is $\sigma(X)$ a subset of $G$?

Comment: Your definition of $G$ is exactly the definition of $\sigma(X)$ (e.g., [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra#σ-algebra_generated_by_random_variable_or_vector)). Are you working with a different definition of $\sigma(X)$?

Comment: Yes, different definition. I'll edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^k$ is measurable with respect to a $\sigma$-field $F$, it means that $F$ contains all sets of the form $\{X \in H\}$ where $H \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^k)$. That is, $G \subseteq F$.

$\sigma(X)$ is defined as $\bigcap F$ where the intersection is over all such $\sigma$-fields. Since $G$ is a sub-$\sigma$-field of each $F$, we must have $G \subseteq \sigma(X)$.

Since $G$ is a $\sigma$-field, it is also one of these $\sigma$-fields in the intersection, so $\sigma(X) \subseteq G$.

Comment: When you say "the sets of the form $[X\in H]$", why don't you simply say the sets $H$? How are the two different?

Comment: @Roberto $[X \in H]$ is presumably shorthand for $\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \in H\}$ which is a subset of $\Omega$. This is different from $H$ which is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$.

Comment: Instead of $[X\in H: H\in B(R^k)]$, could I write $[X^{-1}(H): H\in B(R^k)$?

Comment: @Roberto yes, that notation is sometimes used too